# Homebrew's LLVM "fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found" on macOS

Tags: c, macos, clang, llvm, llvm-clang

1. Install LLVM `brew install llvm`

   ---
2. Edit .zshrc

```
...
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include"
...
```

---

3. Create `hello.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}
```

---

4. Now, when i run `clang -v hello.c`, I get:

```
clang version 8.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_801/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin
 "/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/8.0.1/bin/clang-8" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.14.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name hello.c -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu penryn -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -ggnu-pubnames -target-linker-version 450.3 -v -resource-dir /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/8.0.1/lib/clang/8.0.1 -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/jdriwer/Projects -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 212 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.14.0 -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /var/folders/qg/47c_70qn4wd9tlp18280f7k00000gn/T/hello-4a50cb.o -x c hello.c
clang -cc1 version 8.0.1 based upon LLVM 8.0.1 default target x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/8.0.1/lib/clang/8.0.1/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
hello.c:1:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

---

PS. llvm's `stdio.h` location: `/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/8.0.1/include/c++/v1/stdio.h`
and `/usr/local/opt/llvm ⇒ ../Cellar/llvm/8.0.1` is symbolic link

---

**What's the trouble?**

Comment: You say the location of stdio.h is `/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/8.0.1/include/c++/v1/stdio.h` and you `export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include"`? Doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: `/usr/local/opt/llvm ⇒ ../Cellar/llvm/8.0.1` is symbolic link

Comment: Oh I see, you should have mentioned that in the question. I would suggest you to do a `strace -e trace=open,openat,stat,fstat -s200 -f clang ...` to see specifically where `clang` is looking.

Comment: What is *using* `$LDFLAGS` and `$CPPFLAGS`.  Those environment variables sound like standard `Makefile` variables however `make` doesn't seem to be involved here.  Also setting them in your profile, rather than a `Makefile`, for example doesn't make alot of sense either.

Comment: @trojanfoe these are recommendations form `brew info llvm`

Comment: @jdriwer As you can see from the `-v` output, it's being ignored.  I think you have misunderstood where that should be set.  Also isn't it a prereq of homebrew to have the Xcode command line tools installed?  In which case your answer isn't much help.

Comment: @trojanfoe ignoring because directory is nonexistent. `macOS SDK headers` install his stdio.h (`/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/8.0.1/include/c++/v1/stdio.h` is empty & used `#include_next`). I repeatedly met with this when reinstalling the macOS and always forgot. `Xcode command line` installed, because I use homebrew.

My answer worked for me.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. The answer doesn't work. Did anyone fix this?

Answer (score 6):

If using an external LLVM installation, add these to your `~/.bash_profile`

```sh
LLVM_PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/" # or any other path
LLVM_VERSION="11.0.0"
export PATH="$LLVM_PATH:$PATH"
export SDKROOT=$(xcrun --sdk macosx --show-sdk-path)
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LLVM_PATH/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LLVM_PATH/lib/:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export CPATH="$LLVM_PATH/lib/clang/$LLVM_VERSION/include/"
export LDFLAGS="-L$LLVM_PATH/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I$LLVM_PATH/include"
export CC="$LLVM_PATH/bin/clang"
export CXX="$LLVM_PATH/bin/clang++"
```

(adjust the clang version and the external llvm installation path.)

Then run `source ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 2):

Because `ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include"`

You should install `macOS SDK headers` from `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/`

Comment: i find no /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/ such directory on Catalina

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem on Catalina. There is a ` /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library SDKs` instead.